# Office / Excel 365 - use relative hyperlinks instead of OneDrive

Tags: excel, hyperlink, office365, onedrive

I asked this question on Microsoft TechNet 2 weeks ago but have not received any answer. (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/office-excel-365-use-relative-hyperlinks-instead-of-onedrive/m-p/3068778)

I've recently been "upgraded" to M365 on my work computer, and it's been .... interesting.... There's a lot of changes, a lot of things have moved around. I'm getting used to it, and finding out how to solve things that are new/bugging me. However, I'm yet to find a solution to relative hyperlinks.

I have one Excel Workbook which is my index/summary of a bunch of other spreadsheets/docs. (An example, I have plenty of books with these links!) The index doc shows me where the other information is stored and its status. I want to hyperlink to each of the child spreadsheets/documents, which are in sub-folders of the folder my index workbook is in. E.g. there is one spreadsheet holding the data for each date. Previously, this would just link to "\2022-01-21\dailydata.xlsx". If it was in a parallel folder, it would link to "..\otherProject\docs\mydoc.docx".

Now I'm on M365 and OneDrive, **EVERYTHING** is linked to the online address for the OneDrive doc, e.g. a link to a file in the same folder as the spreadsheet I'm working on, instead of being "TheOtherSheet.xlsx", is instead linked to "https://my-company.sharepoint.com/personal/my_name_and_company/Documents/Documents/Customers/This%20Customer/This%20Project/Issue%20Tracker/Issue%2001/Data/TheOtherSheet.xlsx"...!!!

Opening old files with relative hyperlinks converts the links to the online target.

Yes, the links still work and open the local file when I'm offline (critical!). However, it doesn't make any sense, and it makes the links harder to quickly check / understand visually. I haven't tested what would happen if I were to move a project folder containing relative references to sub-folders; I'm assuming that OneDrive will fix the links...? Sort of afraid to try.

Is there any way to get the old style relative hyperlinks back?

Update: I've just discovered that when I click on one of these hyperlinks to a file on my PC, it downloads it from the cloud, creating a new file in my downloads folder instead of opening the bloody file on my PC!!!! It also takes me to the SharePoint version of linked folders instead of going to the folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following works:

Configure OneDrive to turn OFF "Use Office application to sync Office files" in OneDrive Settings / Office

Comment: Thanks @Torsten, looks like that fixed it - for some of the links at least. The links appear to now point to C:\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\[original file name]. When I reset them to the relative link, they open locally, not on OneDrive. Guess I've got to sit down and write a macro to clean all links in a workbook, shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: In my case the hyperlink was not changed in Excel, but with selecting it the internet browser was launched with asking to login to OneDrive (which I stopped then) instead of opening the file. However, it has finally worked only upon a re-boot of the PC after having changed the mentioned setting.

Comment: I wrote a complement to this solution if it fails to restore the relative path in files where they already been changed to cloud. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/excel-rewrites-my-hyperlinks-to-sharepoint/m-p/3774541/highlight/true#M48180

Comment: I don't see this setting in OneDrive. Has it been moved/renamed or am I looking in the wrong place? I looked for it right clicking the OneDrive icon in the task bar, and going to settings. Checked under "Sync and back up" and "Account" tabs.